# Header comment format

Tags: c++, coding-style, comments, code-formatting, headers

I realize that the "header comment" format varies from programmer to programmer, but what would be an example of a "good" header comment?

Comment: Is this question about only formatting, or about style and content?

Comment: @Macneil Depends on what they mean. For now, I'll play safe and say "both". :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding formatting style, **consistency** is most important to strive for. Make sure every class definition comment *looks* like every other one, every method comment looks like every other one, etc.

So, if you're modifying *existing* code, make sure you follow their formatting style. The comments (and, to an extent, code) should look like only one person has worked on the file. If you're starting a new project, **pick one style format and stick with it.**

Places to start looking:

- [Google style guides](http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/) (C++, JavaScript, Objective-C, and Python)
- [Oracle JavaDoc comment example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#format)